# Firebase ValueEventListener not firing at all

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I am simply trying to fire this Firebase ValueEventListener. I have set break points inside of the listeners to check if they are firing, and they are not. I am not sure why it isn't working, as everything looks fine to me. Is there any reason relating to Firebase that this app would not be working?

```
package sampleproj.wisen.android.sampleproj;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DatabaseReference d = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        d.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                int r = 0;
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

**Update:** 
here is the structure of the database: 
[image]

I have already tried accessing the database at the deepest child level. The point is to retrieve a list of messages between two users.

```
    final String senderUsername = "WiseNN";
    final String recipeintUsername = "tellMeWhen2Go";
    final String messagesKey = "messages";
    DatabaseReference DBRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            DatabaseReference DBMsgsRef = DBRef.child("privateChat").child(senderUsername).child(recipeintUsername).child(messagesKey).getRef();
```

Comment: Share your database structure.

Comment: I have uploaded the structure of the database

Comment: Post Expanded structure of document which you want to retrieve .

Comment: posted an updated database structure

Comment: 1. does it give you any errors on your logcat? 2. Change `DatabaseReference DBMsgsRef = DBRef.child("privateChat").child(senderUsername).child(recipeintUsername).child(messagesKey).getRef();` to `DatabaseReference DBMsgsRef = DBRef.child("privateChat").child(senderUsername).child(recipeintUsername).child(messagesKey);` 3. Check your database rules

Answer (score 1):

Try to put `"privateChat/WiseNN/tellMeWhen2Go/messages/"` as a DB reference in the getReference() method.

```
DatabaseReference d = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("privateChat/WiseNN/tellMeWhen2Go/messages/");
```

Comment: I have tried: `/privateChat`, `privateChat` & `privateChat/`. None of these seem to work.

Comment: May I know what's the data inside the "privateChat"?

Comment: to retrieve a list of messages between two users, i think you need considering the design of the data structure because Firebase has limitation on the query function.

Comment: Not sure why this was upvoted...this had nothing to do with the issue. This is misleading.

Answer (score 0):

```
String data, message;
DatabaseReference d = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("privateChat").child("WiseNN").child("tellMeWhen2Go").child("messages");
d.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            data = ds.child("data").getValue().toString();
            message = ds.child("message").getValue().toString();
            // similarly for sender & time

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: I hope this will resolve your problem. So accept the answer and upvote it too, so it can be useful for others.

Comment: This and the code that I have above is exactly the same. However, I have copied/pasted your code and tried to run it. It does not work. I know there is nothing wrong with the code, is there any other reason the listener wouldn't fire. Maybe something to do with android studio version, or firebase config?

Comment: The another reason could be due to Firebase rules. See for firebase rules.

Comment: I figured it out, it wasn't the code (as I have previously stated). I think it was due to some sort of firebase glitch. I have used this same code to call firebase previously with no issues. It just all of a sudden stopped working. But it is working fine now.

Comment: I wrote my own answer because none of the answers provided worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**I am writing my own answer, as I have just figured it out.**

I think this was due to some sort of Firebase glitch. When I logged into my google console, I saw that I had no database (there was nothing in it), when I know in-fact one existed. However, this would make sense as to why the callback functions were not firing.

Oddly enough, I cloned a new example firebase android app from GitHub, added it to my Firebase app in the google console, then wrote a new object to the realtime-database (from the new example android app). After doing this, my entire firebase database structure literally reappeared.

After that, I went back to the main app I was originally working on, and called firebase using the exact same code that was previously there...and it worked. I know this may not sound reasonable, but this is literally what just happened.

Answer (score 0):

You missed .child("messages");

```
DatabaseReference DBRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference DBMsgsRef = DBRef.child("privateChat").child(senderUsername).child(recipeintUsername).child("messages").child(messagesKey).getRef();
```